# Vue 2 TSX -> React TSX .. how to make them play nice

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, tsx

I have an app written using Vue 2 (+ vue-tsx-support + vue-class-component + vue-property-decorator) .. so my Vue 2 components are already TSX classes ..

I would like to make a gradual move towards React ..

I've come across https://github.com/akxcv/vuera and gave it a stab a while ago .. but it seems like there is hardcode conflicts in the typings when it comes to TSX.

Both React and vue-tsx-support hook into the default TSX typings for what an element is .. etc ..

Does anyone know is there is a viable way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If your codebase has JSX and mixed use for both Vue and React, you can set per-file how to interpret the JSX tags:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#jsxFactory

Comment: oh yea .. perhaps this may help .. I did notice this factory stuff was added in a little while ago and vue-tsx-support was updated to use a custom factory instead of using the default mode .. 

I would still need to set some files to use `react` TSX mode .. and the other to the vue custom mode .. 

Is it somehow possible to override the `jsx` setting itself though and not just the factory?

ie: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#jsx